# I got twice contact while Ball A fall down to Ball B

Tags: flutter, flame

I try to practice the following effect: When a balls fall down to another ball of the same `BodyComponent` and is already lying on the ground, one of them should be removed from the screen.

Here is my attempt:

```
 @override
  void beginContact(Object other, Contact contact) {
    if (other is Ball) {
        if (position.y < other.position.y) {
          shouldRemoved = true;
          other.levelUp = true;
        } else {
          other.shouldRemoved = true;
          levelUp = true;
          print('ballA shouldRemoved: $shouldRemoved levelup: $levelUp  |||| ballB ${other.shouldRemoved}  levelup: ${other.levelUp} ');
        }
      }
    }
```

And I got twice print results:

```
flutter: ballA shouldRemoved: false levelup: true  |||| ballB true  levelup: false
flutter: ballA shouldRemoved: true levelup: true  |||| ballB true  levelup: true
```

My goal is only one ball get removed and another ball should get levelUp true, but now since two balls are removed. It is from a old version flame which uses `ContactCallback<Ball, Ball>`, and it works, but now I updated to latest version flame, since there is no `gameRef.addContactCallback`, I do have no idea where is the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the collision callback `onCollision` or `onCollisionStart()`. A description can be found in the [docs](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.6.0/flame/collision_detection.html#collisioncallbacks).

An example looks like this

```dart
class BallGame extends FlameGame with HasCollisionDetection {
  // ...
}
```

```dart
class Ball extends PositionComponent with CollisionCallbacks {
  @override
  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> points, PositionComponent other) {
    if (other is Ball) {
      // Determine which ball to remove based on their properties.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi jraufeisen, thanks for your answer, but maybe the balls are BodyComponent, anyway the onCollision has no reaction, only with ContactCallbacks I got the feedback, does onCollision not work with forge2D?